# Pyinstaller: cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-oracle

I have a simple python script that imports cx_Oracle and then makes an sql query. It all works fine when run from python. I have Oracle SQL developer installed on my computer, which is free.

When I then compile the program with 'pyinstaller main.py' everything compiles fine and i can also start the problem. But as soon as an SQL query is made from that program, the following runtime error occurs:

cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

I have tried the following:

- moving all .dll and .jar files from oracle to the build directory as here: https://sourceforge.net/p/cx-oracle/mailman/cx-oracle-users/thread/g7nbks$tl$1@ger.gmane.org/
- excluding oci.dll with the pyinstaller main.py --exclude oci.dll option from pyinstaller
- checked that my ORACLE_HOME is set correctly to: - C:\Users\nyname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\instantclient_12_1

None of this has worked.

Any suggestions what else I can do are much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution:

When running pyinstaller as normal one file will be missing in the compilation. It needs to be manually included:

For that you need to edit  the line with as follows:

```
binaries+[('oraociei12.dll','oraociei12.dll','BINARY')],
```

make sure that oraociei12.dll is in the current folder.

```
block_cipher = None
    a = Analysis(['LDM-shark.py'],
                 pathex=['C:\\Users\\dicknic\\AppData\\Local\\Home\\dev\\LDM'],
                 binaries=None,
                 datas=None,
                 hiddenimports=[],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
              a.scripts,
              a.binaries+[('oraociei12.dll','oraociei12.dll','BINARY')],
              a.zipfiles,
              a.datas,
              name='mainprogram',
              debug=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=True,
              console=True )
```

In a second step run pyinstaller again but with the spec file. pyinstaller mainprogram.spec

and it will work

Comment: I tried this solution as well but to no avail. Still keep getting the same error when I run the .exe on another machine. Do you still need an oracle instant client installation along with this or should the pyinstaller embed that into the .exe by default. Please help

Comment: works well for me. You need an oracle instant client installation

Answer (score 2):

I used the following rule:

```
a.binaries+[('oraociei12.dll','C:\\oracle\\product\\instantclient_12_1\\oraociei12.dll','BINARY')],
```

The second element of the tuple is the complete path of the DLL. It's better to know this...

There is a open issue on github for the Pyinstaller project at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1924

I hope this could help

Comment: Yes I opened this issue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The solution described above worked for me, with one small modification - I had to include an extra DLL:

```
a.binaries+[('oraociei12.dll','C:\\instantclient_12_1\\oraociei12.dll','BINARY'), ('oraons.dll','C:\\instantclient_12_1\\oraons.dll','BINARY')]
```

Note: I am running Python 3.5 64-bit, PyInstaller 3.2.1, Oracle InstantClient 12.1 64-bit, and Windows 7 64-bit. Hope this helps someone.